# Polygon collision detection implementation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, polygons

I'm trying to write my own implementation of separating axis theorem but I'm have some trouble getting it to work as accurately as I want. I can't say for sure, but it looks like it's saying there's a collision when an imaginary box around the shapes collide like in the first shape. But the second shape works perfectly.

Here's the vertex data for the square (exact coordinates):

```
vertsx = [ 200, 220, 220, 200 ]
vertsy = [ 220, 220, 200, 200 ]
```

Here's the vertex data for test shape 1 (relative to mouse):

```
vertsx = [ -10,   0,  10, 10, -10 ]
vertsy = [ -10, -50, -10, 10,  10 ]
```

And lastly here's the vertex data for test shape 2 (relative to mouse):

```
vertsx = [ -10,   0,  10, 10, -10 ]
vertsy = [ -10, -20, -10, 10,  10 ]
```

Just for clarification the translated coordinates are the ones that are tested and these have shapes have been tested with the coordinates ordered as shown.

[image]

Here's the actual function.

```
function collisionConvexPolygon ( vertsax, vertsay, vertsbx, vertsby ) {
    var alen = vertsax.length;
    var blen = vertsbx.length;
    // Loop for axes in Shape A
    for ( var i = 0, j = alen - 1; i < alen; j = i++ ) {
        // Get the axis
        var vx =    vertsax[ j ] - vertsax[ i ];
        var vy = -( vertsay[ j ] - vertsay[ i ] );
        var len = Math.sqrt( vx * vx + vy * vy );

        vx /= len;
        vy /= len;

        // Project shape A
        var max0 = vertsax[ 0 ] * vx + vertsay[ 0 ] * vy, min0 = max0;
        for ( k = 1; k < alen; k++ ) {
            var proja = vertsax[ k ] * vx + vertsay[ k ] * vy;

            if ( proja > max0 ) {
                max0 = proja;
            }
            else if ( proja < min0 ) {
                min0 = proja;
            }
        }
        // Project shape B
        var max1 = vertsbx[ 0 ] * vx + vertsby[ 0 ] * vy, min1 = max1;
        for ( var k = 1; k < blen; k++ ) {
            var projb = vertsbx[ k ] * vx + vertsby[ k ] * vy;

            if ( projb > max1 ) {
                max1 = projb;
            }
            else if ( projb < min1 ) {
                min1 = projb;
            }
        }
        // Test for gaps
        if ( !axisOverlap( min0, max0, min1, max1 ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Loop for axes in Shape B (same as above)
    for ( var i = 0, j = blen - 1; i < blen; j = i++ ) {
        var vx =    vertsbx[ j ] - vertsbx[ i ];
        var vy = -( vertsby[ j ] - vertsby[ i ] );
        var len = Math.sqrt( vx * vx + vy * vy );

        vx /= len;
        vy /= len;

        var max0 = vertsax[ 0 ] * vx + vertsay[ 0 ] * vy, min0 = max0;
        for ( k = 1; k < alen; k++ ) {
            var proja = vertsax[ k ] * vx + vertsay[ k ] * vy;

            if ( proja > max0 ) {
                max0 = proja;
            }
            else if ( proja < min0 ) {
                min0 = proja;
            }
        }
        var max1 = vertsbx[ 0 ] * vx + vertsby[ 0 ] * vy, min1 = max1;
        for ( var k = 1; k < blen; k++ ) {
            var projb = vertsbx[ k ] * vx + vertsby[ k ] * vy;

            if ( projb > max1 ) {
                max1 = projb;
            }
            else if ( projb < min1 ) {
                min1 = projb;
            }
        }
        if ( !axisOverlap( min0, max0, min1, max1 ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'll try other shapes if you need me to.

Here's my `axisOverlap` function.

```
function axisOverlap ( a0, a1, b0, b1 ) {
    return !( a0 > b1 || b0 > a1 );
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `axisOverlap()` function too?

Comment: Could you please try this without inverting the direction of vy?

Comment: @Asad Yes, unfortunately it didn't change the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out!

I began plotting number lines on paper and realized the problem was that my axes weren't calculated correctly. To calculate a perpendicular vector you need to **swap the x and y coordinates** and THEN invert one, I completely forgot to swap the coordinates.

The new code

```
var vx =    vertsay[ i ] - vertsay[ j ];
var vy = -( vertsax[ i ] - vertsax[ j ] );
```

Comment: If you have solved your question, then mark your answer as _the_ answer!